# Can not open localhost:8088. Trying to install Hadoop3 on Windows10

Tags: hadoop, windows-10, hadoop-yarn

localhost:9870 is working fine. the problem is localhost:8088. Did they move it same as 9870?

Answer (score 2):

No.  As stated in [Apache Hadoop 3.0.0](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/):

> **Default ports of multiple services have been changed.**
>
> Previously, the default ports of multiple Hadoop services were in the Linux ephemeral port range (32768-61000). This meant that at startup, services would sometimes fail to bind to the port due to a conflict with another application.
>
> These conflicting ports have been moved out of the ephemeral range, affecting the NameNode, Secondary NameNode, DataNode, and KMS. Our documentation has been updated appropriately, but see the release notes for HDFS-9427 and HADOOP-12811 for a list of port changes.

Since the YARN ports were never in the ephemeral port range, they didn't need to be changed.

This is confirmed by looking at the [yarn-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) for Hadoop 3.0.0.

> | yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address |   ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088 | The http address of the RM web application. If only a host is provided as the value, the webapp will be served on a random port.